# U.S. Bank ATM cards and credit card acceptance in Russia 2015,

Tags: money, russia, payment-cards

Do ATM cards extracting money from US banks work in Russia? Will I have a problem using credit cards that are on US banks in Russia?

Comment: What do you mean? What network does your card belong to (visa, MasterCard, Maestro, or else)? As far as I know cash machines provide cash on that criteria only, regardless of the country the card was issued

Answer (score 4):

If you show up in Russia and start using your debit card at ATM's there's a possibility that your bank's detection program may flag it up for analysis.  This would happen if using a Russian ATM is outside of your standard usage pattern.

At that point, the bank will start trying to call your mobile or send you email asking you to contact them, and if they cannot reach you then yes, they might put a block on your card.

To avoid something like that, you can send your bank a notification email along the lines of...

> I expect to be in Stavropol during 20 July - 23 July and in Tver on 24
>   July - 26 July.  I will be using local ATM's to replenish my pocket
>   money and please honour withdrawals up to USD 200 per day.  My mobile number is... and my email is...

Some banks (like HSBC) even have a form you can fill out online.

Other than that, there is no cause for thinking that a debit card issued by a Fed regulated bank would not work in Russia.  I don't use American Express at ATM's, but can attest that Visa and Mastercard debit cards work in the cities I mentioned above along with Moscow and Peter.

To help canonicalise this answer, the same would hold true for FCA regulated banks and ECB supervised banks.

Comment: Can only add that you should rely only on two main types of cards: Visa & Mastercard. Other ones, such as American Express or something like that, can be a problem as they not so widely accepted even in big cities..

Comment: Minor note: my experience with US banks is that you can't send them an email: there is no email address set up to receive account specific inquiries (partly because there is no good way to authenticate them). You'll have to use either an online form or the telephone (number should be on your card). Also, it seems that some banks no longer accept this sort of travel notification at all.